# R shiny: cannot download interactive report

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am looking to download an interactive R shiny document and save it to a file for other users (that do not own R or Rstudio) to view and interact with. The R shiny document runs fine, but the download button fails when I attempt to save the downloaded file somewhere. Here is my code; I used the dataset 'cars' so the errors can be reproduced:

Shiny code:

```
library(knitr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

x <- cars
x$dist_cut <- cut(x$dist, breaks = c(-1, 25, 50, 75, 100, 9999), 
                       labels = c("0-25", "26-50", "51-75", "76-100", ">100"))

t.cut <- table(x$dist_cut)

# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Cars Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout( position = "right",

                 # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                 sidebarPanel(

                   # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----
                   selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                               label = "Choose a range for dist:",
                               choices = c("show all", ">100", "76-100", "51-75", "26-50", "0-25")),
                   downloadButton('downloadReport')

                 ),

                 # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                 mainPanel(

                   # Output: Barplot ----
                   plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot"),

                   # Output: HTML table with requested number of observations ----

                   DT::dataTableOutput("view")


                 )
  )
)

# Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Return the requested dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "show all" = x,
           ">100" = x[x$dist_cut == ">100",],
           "76-100" = x[x$dist_cut == "76-100",],
           "51-75" = x[x$dist_cut == "51-75",],
           "26-50" = x[x$dist_cut == "26-50",],
           "0-25" = x[x$dist_cut == "0-25",])
  })

  # display the plot
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    barplot(t.cut, beside = TRUE, col = c("green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "red"), main = "Cars sorted by dist", ylim = c(0, 20), cex.main = 1.5, xlab = "dist", ylab = "Frequency")

  })

  # create the DT datatable
  output$view = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(datasetInput(), filter = 'top', 
                  options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, nrow(x)), pageLength = 5))

  })

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste0("report", ".html"),
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.rmd")
      file.copy("report.rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(data = x,
                     title = "Plot Title",
                     limits = c(-10,10))
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }     
  )

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Rmarkdown code:

````
---
output: html_document
params:
    data: NULL
    limits: NULL
    title: "Cars Data"
title: "`r params$title`"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
print(params$title)
barplot(table(params$x$dist_cut), beside = TRUE, col = c("green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "red"), main = "Cars Split by dist", ylim = c(0, 20), cex.main = 1.5, xlab = "dist", ylab = "Frequency") 
library(DT) 
datatable(params$x, filter = 'top', options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, nrow(x)), pageLength = 5))
```
````

With this code, I receive the following warnings and errors after clicking on the download button:

```
Warning: Error in : path for html_dependency not provided
  [No stack trace available]
Warning in min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
```

I also receive a pop-up window titled "Download Failed" stating:

```
Error downloading {R shiny html link} - server replied: Internal Service Error
```

I have spent about a week trying to debug this and I have not quite figured out what I am missing. I am new to R shiny web applications and would really like to allow non-R users to view these interactive reports to help them do their jobs. I hope this is enough information to help find a solution to my problem.

Thanks!

Update: When I save the HTML file and open it in internet explorer, I only see the title (Cars Data) at the top of the page and the sidebar panel (containing the drop-down box and the download button). In addition, I get a prompt stating "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls" and nothing happens when I press "Allow Blocked Content." Does this have anything to do with the issue?

I apologize for not posting a reproducible example originally: this is my first stackoverflow post.

Comment: Thanks for posting a real [MCVE] of your problem! I'm pretty sure I was able to solve it now

Answer (score 2):

The `server replied: Internal Service Error` is just a generic error that means your `.Rmd` wasn't able to be rendered correctly. Your real problem is likely with your `.Rmd`.

If you look at the stack trace error, it says:

```
Warning in min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

When you click on the download button, it runs the `render` function on your `.Rmd` and tries to render it. From the look of the error, you're trying to plot something, but some or all of the objects your plot function is trying to use to make the plot can't be found, so it fails with an error.

Since the data for your plot comes from the shiny app, you have to pass it into the `.Rmd`. The better way to do this is to pass in the data your `.Rmd` needs directly as a list passed to the `params=` argument of `rmarkdown::render`.

```
# NOTE: downloadHandler must be assigned to the ID of your downloadButton
output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste0("report", ".html"),
    content = function(file) {
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.rmd")
        file.copy("report.rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        #  these can be any time of R objects
        #  that you want your .Rmd to have access to
        params <- list(data = x,
                       title = "Plot Title",
                       limits = c(-10,10))
        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        #  child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        #  from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
    }     
)
```

Now in your `.Rmd` you define those parameters in the header:

```
---
output: html_document
params:
    data: NULL
    limits: NULL
    title: "Default title"
title: "`r params$title`"
---
```

And then use it by accessing the `params` object. Once you pass a object into the `.Rmd` as a `param`, you can access it in the `.Rmd` using the name that you gave in the params-list. So, even though your data frame is named `x` in your shiny app, since you passed it in to the parameter `data`, you'll access it in the `.Rmd` using `params$data`.

````
```{r}
print(params$title)
barplot(table(params$data$dist_cut), beside = TRUE,
        col = c("green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "red"),
        main = "Cars Split by dist", ylim = c(0, 20),
        cex.main = 1.5, xlab = "dist", ylab = "Frequency")

library(DT)
DT::datatable(params$data, filter = 'top',
              options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, nrow(params$data)),
                             pageLength = 5))
```
````

Passing in objects explicitly through the `params` argument (and rendering the `.rmd` in a new environment) makes sure that the data you need is available to your `.rmd`, that it has the *correct* data (especially important in Shiny where the contents of your objects may change in unexpected ways due to user input) and prevents namespace collisions (where you have unexpected objects with the same name in the environment)

Comment: This worked! I have a couple of follow-up questions: 1) In order for this to work, I had to copy my R-markdown file and paste in a temporary directory (C:\Users\U1335567\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkHyWYg). If not, R could not find the report. Will I have to do this every time I try to download a report, or can I change the code so that it reads the markdown file from my working directory?

Comment: 2) I have another report with interactive graphs. In the dataframe "cars" -- using R shiny -- say I want to display a bar chart of 'dist' for a particular 'speed' (using a numericInput() box to select the speed). The bar chart would change depending on the speed that I selected. Would this functionality be lost upon downloading, or is there a way to preserve it? Let me know if you need me to give you a verifiable example, if my question is unclear.

Comment: These lines: `tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.rmd")` and `file.copy("report.rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)` should copy your report into a temporary directory for rendering. You shouldn't have to move your file manually. As for your second question, you can pass any information that you want to your `.rmd` using params, so there's no reason you can't pass in your chosen speed and use it to subset your data or whatever.

Comment: If you have more questions, though, you really should ask another question. The Q&A format here only works if you have a specific question with a specific answer. There's no limit to how many questions you can ask, so if you have further questions, just ask another question